# How can I use columns I create in my select clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm curious if it's possible to use columns I create in my select clause for other fields.

For example, I have this query --

```
SELECT 
    users.officeid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN users.active = 1 THEN user.id ELSE NULL END) as active_users,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN users.total = 1  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as total_users,
    active_users / total_users

FROM users  
GROUP BY 1
```

I would like to have another column that is active_users / total_users, but I get the error -->

column "active_users" does not exist in users

Do I need to put these in a common table expression and then select from them? Is there another solution? Thanks!

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96563/77009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As ..." only renames the column for the query output.

If you want to calculate this on the go and avoid creating an additional column you can do the following:

```
select count(column1), count(column1), 
count(column1) / count(column2)
from table
```

You could also create a materialized view for it.

Comment: Same comment, 1 of 2:  Acceptable answer, but bear in mind bigint / bigint = bigint, meaning your result will probably be zero.  You probably need to cast one of those as a numeric if this represents a subset, which seems to be the case per the question

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was missing -- I didn't know that As was only for the query output

Answer (score 2):

```
with cccik as( SELECT 
    users.officeid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN users.active = 1 THEN user.id ELSE NULL END) as active_users,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN users.total = 1  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as total_users,


FROM users  
GROUP BY 1)
select *, (active_users / total_users) from ccckik 
-- you can filter by officeid
-- where officeid = 5
```

Comment: Same comment, 2 of 2:  Acceptable answer, but bear in mind bigint / bigint = bigint, meaning your result will probably be zero.  You probably need to cast one of those as a numeric if this represents a subset, which seems to be the case per the question

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing that

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select officeid, active_users, total_users, active_users / total_users
from
(
SELECT 
    users.officeid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN users.active = 1 THEN user.id ELSE NULL END) as active_users,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN users.total = 1  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as total_users
FROM users  
GROUP BY 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful